# What is the best way to organize a uitableviewdatasource with sections and rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This seems like a very basic question at first, but suppose I have a data model as follows:

```
@interface MyModel
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *index;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *sectionIndex;

   ...
@end
```

It's fairly trivial to write the UITableView dataSource functions:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

by building dictionaries and logic to map index paths to the datasource objects. But is there some objective-c construct that lets me do this without writing this logic? I would think that this model pattern is common enough that there should be some objective-c pattern I could use.

Comment: It's common enough that everybody has there own solution but not common enough for Apple to provide one.

Comment: A common pattern I use is to create an array of section objects. Each section object is comprised of an array of items and a title.